# add multiple scheduled notifications using flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications

I've been working on an adhan app using flutter and I'm working on the scheduled notification using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package. Using the `.zonedSchedule` I can only display notification once.

```
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings = AndroidInitializationSettings("icon");
  IOSInitializationSettings iosInitializationSettings = IOSInitializationSettings();
  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidInitializationSettings,
      iOS: iosInitializationSettings);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
```

and for the Notification detail

```
    var android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    "$id", channel,
    importance: Importance.max,
    sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('adhan'),
    playSound: true,
  );
  var ios = IOSNotificationDetails();
  var platform = NotificationDetails(android: android, iOS: ios);

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
```

and used it as

```
    _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        1,
        "title",
        "dhuhr",
        tz.TZDateTime.from(prayerTimes.dhuhr!, location),
        platform,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation
            .absoluteTime,
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time
    );
  _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      2,
      "title",
      "Asr",
      tz.TZDateTime.from(prayerTimes.asr!, location),
      platform,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation
          .absoluteTime,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time
  );
```

the problem I'm facing is that if the time matches with the current prayer time it works fine. but when it's time for the next schedule it doesn't display anything.

So how can I display notification multiple times in a day?

Comment: Any updates about the problem